# Use flex-output and lua style file with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, import, osm2pgsql

I want to use `osm2pgsql`. I have a `osm.pbf` file for whole Europe from [geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html).
I am only interested in features (`point` and `polygons`) containing the tags

**Religious**

`amenity=place_of_worship` (is mandatory for `religion`)

-> `religion=christian`

-> `religion=islamic`

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:religion

**Tourism**

`tourism=museum`

`tourism=attraction`

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:tourism

How would I create a `style.lua` file so that I only import `point` and `polygon` features with the associated tags above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the `flex output` option from `osm2pgsql` and created two `.lua` files.

```
-- import.lua --

-- import the helper functions
local funcs = require "helpers"
local tables = {}

-- this creates the table for point and its columns
tables.religion = osm2pgsql.define_node_table('religion_point', {
    { column = 'osm_type',     type = 'text', not_null = true },
    { column = 'name',     type = 'text', not_null = true},
    { column = 'geom',     type = 'point' },
}, { schema = 'public' })

-- this creates the table for polygon and its columns
tables.religion_polygon = osm2pgsql.define_way_table('religion_polygon', {
    { column = 'osm_type',     type = 'text' , not_null = true},
    { column = 'name',     type = 'text', not_null = true},
    { column = 'geom',     type = 'multipolygon' },
}, { schema = 'public' })

function osm2pgsql.process_node(object)
    -- We are only interested in religion details
    if not object.tags.religion then
        return
    end

    -- We are only interested in objects that have a name
    if funcs.is_empty(object.tags.name) then
        return
    end

    funcs.clean_tags(object.tags)
    -- this reduces it to the tags 'christian' and 'muslim'
    if 
    object.tags.religion == 'christian' or 
    object.tags.religion == 'muslim' or
    then
        -- Using grab_tag() removes from remaining key/value saved to Pg
        local osm_type = object:grab_tag('religion')
        local name = object:grab_tag('name')
        tables.religion:add_row({
            osm_type = osm_type,
            name = name,
            geom = { create = 'point' }
        })
    end
end

-- Change function name here
function religion_process_way(object)
    -- We are only interested in highways
    if not object.tags.religion then
        return
    end

    -- We are only interested in objects that have a name
    if funcs.is_empty(object.tags.name) then
        return
    end

    funcs.clean_tags(object.tags)
    if 
    object.tags.religion == 'christian' or 
    object.tags.religion == 'muslim' or
    then
        local osm_type = object:grab_tag('religion')
        local name = object:grab_tag('name')

        if object.is_closed and funcs.has_area_tags(object.tags) then
            tables.religion_polygon:add_row({
                osm_type = osm_type,
                name = name,
                geom = { create = 'area' }
            })
        end
    end
end

if osm2pgsql.process_way == nil then
    -- Change function name here
    osm2pgsql.process_way = religion_process_way
else
    local nested = osm2pgsql.process_way
    osm2pgsql.process_way = function(object)
        local object_copy = funcs.deep_copy(object)
        nested(object)
        -- Change function name here
        religion_process_way(object_copy)
    end
end


-- helpers.lua --

-- tags we don't need
local function clean_tags(tags)
    tags.odbl = nil
    tags.created_by = nil
    tags.source = nil
    tags['source:ref'] = nil

    return next(tags) == nil
end

-- check for empty object
local function is_empty(s)
    return s == nil or s == ''
end

-- deep_copy based on copy2: https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/81333721109155b2d244
local function deep_copy(obj)
    if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return obj end
    local res = setmetatable({}, getmetatable(obj))
    for k, v in pairs(obj) do res[deep_copy(k)] = deep_copy(v) end
    return res
end

-- function that looks at the tags and decides if this is possibly an area.
local function has_area_tags(tags)
    if tags.area == 'yes' then
        return true
    end
    if tags.area == 'no' then
        return false
    end

    return tags.amenity
        or tags.building
        or tags.historic
        or tags.landuse
        or tags.leisure
        or tags.man_made
        or tags.natural
        or tags.place
        or tags.tourism
        or tags['abandoned:amenity']
        or tags['abandoned:building']
end


return { clean_tags = clean_tags, is_empty = is_empty, deep_copy = deep_copy, has_area_tags = has_area_tags }
```

And then run it with

```
$ osm2pgsql -c -d <DATABASENAME> -U postgres -H localhost -O flex -S ./<NAME>.lua ./<FILENAME>.osm.pbf
```

Sources for the Script

- https://github.com/rustprooflabs/pgosm-flex
- https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql-website/blob/master/_manual/06-flex-output.md